In powershell, process created by start-process hangs after it completes
In powershell, process(msbuild process) created by start-process hangs after it completes
start-process -Wait -NoNewWindow msbuild  -argumentlist "solution.sln", "/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64", "/target:projectname"

In the above, if there's something to compile, the msbuild process hangs after it finishes all jobs, and I have to use 'ctl-c' to terminate it. If there's nothing to compile, the process terminates successfully.
Software versions
PSVersion                      7.4.3
MSBUILD
   - MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e
   - Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1


tried to start a script which warps msbuild; failed
Tested different versions of msbuild; all failed


Does the same thing happen if you execute it from a regular Windows Command Prompt? (i.e. is this a PowerShell-related issue or something more specific to MSBuild?)

I have no explanation for the behavior, and the following, general advice may or may not make a difference; its upshot is: run msbuild solution.sln '/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64' /target:projectname instead of using Start-Process

To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console (terminal), call them directly (some.exe or c:\path\to\some.exe ... or & 'c:\path with spaces\to\some.exe' ... or & $exePathStoredInVariable ...). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via $LASTEXITCODE. Do not use Start-Process (or the System.Diagnostics.Process API it is based on). See this answer and this guidance.


I must point out:  This problem does not reproduce every time. It often appears on some days, and rarely appears or even does not appear on other days. 2) I use msbuild directly often and it terminates normally.  3) The reason I must use start-process is that I have many solutions(for clang, vc2015 and vc2022) to maintain and it is good to manage them in one command-line window.


The problem just reproduced. It's a headache, because I want to write a batch script to call start-process more times; if one of them hangs, the other will not be executed.
